# YouTube Data API v3 - Comment threads request doesn't return count of total results

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I perform the following YouTube Data API request to list commentThreads, `pageInfo/totalResults` isn't returned in the response.

I expect `pageInfo/totalResults` to be returned [per the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#response).

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?part=snippet%2Creplies&videoId=dGidYBqBHVw&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

For example, if you use the [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#try-it), and enter:

- **part**: snippet,replies
- **videoId**: dGidYBqBHVw

The response returns `200 OK` with the rest of the data, but omits the `pageInfo/totalResults` value:

```
"pageInfo": {
  "resultsPerPage": 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the request you posted and got

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#commentThreadListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sGDdEsjSJ_SnACpEvVQ6MtTzkrI/p78HIXZZWNay4CG1YPcS0NCjiOw\"",
 "nextPageToken": "Cg0QnNnZ0pTFxwIgACgBEhQIABCI5cnWjcTHAhi4kKTI3bvHAhgCIBQondOJjuX1p_e5AQ==",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 20,
  "resultsPerPage": 20
 },...
}
```

Seems like it's been fixed.

Comment: Not really... Why is the totalResults equal to resultsPerPage even when there are many more comments on the video ?

Answer (score 0):

I have also tired for it. It works for me. Youtube or Google usually change their apis format or data structures. It is not a big thing.